# How to determine class of these amplifiers?

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit, datasheet

Is there a way to figure out the class of the following IC amplifiers from their datasheets?

https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000134.pdf

http://www.unisonic.com.tw/datasheet/MC3419.pdf

Comment: Well, the ST one has a full schematic of its internals. They're probably going to be class AB unless otherwise specified, anyway; that gives good performance and is common in op amps.

Comment: In the other one you can infer it's not Class A from the quiescent current, and probably Class B from the fairly poor distortion figure. but it's not so certain.

Answer (score 0):

There is no systematic method to determine classes of specific amplifier other than retro-engineering the schematics.

However lot's of AOPs are AB or B as said in comments. Sometimes it's also configurable regarding the inputs / outputs you use.

Answer (score 0):

Both the [TDA2822M](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000134.pdf) and the [MC3419](http://www.unisonic.com.tw/datasheet/MC3419.pdf) look like class AB amplifiers to me.

I derive this by looking at their maximum output power into the load. Both can drive a fairly low impedance speaker (4 or 8 ohms) so that means they must be able to deliver quite some current.

The maximum output current rating is 1 A (TDA2822M) and 0.25 A (MC3419).

So now I know the output stages can deliver a decent amount of current, for a 100% class A amplifier the quiescent current would have to be in the same ballpark.

So I look at the quiescent currents when these ICs are operating, they're only a couple of mA so **significantly less** than the maximum output drive currents.

Up to output currents of a few mA (the value is related to the quiescent current) the amplifier would work in **Class A**.

But as soon as more power needs to be delivered, the amplifier will work in **Class B**.

So my conclusion: they're both **Class AB**.